# Return zero when cut command doesn't return any value

Tags: linux, bash, cut

I have a scenario where

```
extract_content='60^123'

extract_count=$(echo $extract_content | cut -d^ -f1)
```

Then

```
extract_count='60' is what I achieve
```

Now sometimes

```
extract_content=?
```

Then I want

```
extract_count='0'
```

How can I achieve that using `cut` command

Comment: `extract_count=$(if [ "$extract_content" = '?' ]; then echo 0; else echo $extract_content | cut -d^ -f1; fi)` ? Why don't you just check if `extract_content` is empty, and if it is, assign a `0` to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `cut` at all.

```
extract_content='60^123'

extract_count=0
[[ $extract_content =~ ([[:digit:]]+)\^ ]] && extract_count=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```

or

```
[[ $extract_content =~ ([[:digit:]]+)\^ ]]
extract_count=${BASH_REMATCH[1]:-0}
```

or even

```
extract_count=${extract_content%%^*}
extract_count=${extract_count:-0}
```

Comment: Should petition Meta to allow a point-per-solution-per-person in a single answer `:)`